# Is there a ig-Nobel prize dinner?

Tags: food, modern

I know that there’s a Nobel prize dinner & that there’s the ig-Nobel prize for making you laugh and then think: my question is this, is there a ig-Nobel prize dinner? I figured that it would be fairly modern if it helps as the ig-Nobel prizes are fairly modern as well.

Comment: Please, do (and document) preliminary research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Posting this here as comments don't allow much formatting...]

I've honestly no idea what the answer is, but when you google "ig-Nobel prize dinner" you get [summaries](https://www.chronicle.com/article/Science-Prizes-From-Nobel-to/46231) along the lines of:

> or in the case of the Ig Nobel, far beyond a plaque and a free dinner

Which invite to think that, yes: there is such a dinner, and it's basically the only thing you get on top of a plaque.